# Looking for a word for a specific chimney

Tags: word-request

What would you call this type of chimney?[image]

[image]

[image]

In German, it is 'Mantelschornstein'

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I suspect we would call it a "Mantelschornstein", since we don't really have those things. Maybe a "kitchen chimney".

Comment: Yes, I googled different versions, but nothing came up. One suggestion was 'a shell chimney', but I think that is something else. Google translate offered me 'mantle chimney' :-), but it didn't provide any Google entries. Somewhere in a translated text, I saw 'a smoke hood', but isn't that something like 'a gas mask'?

Comment: *Mantel* is a coat or covering. Does this chimney have two layers, like an inner chimney and a surrounding airspace within the visible outer wall? If that's what it is we might call it a "jacketed" chimney in English.

Comment: If there's no airspace between the inner chimney and the outer wall, it might be a *lined* chimney with an inner flue of tile (or sheet metal in more modern examples), supported by the stone masonry we see from the outside.

Comment: I added more pictures to approximately show what it looks like. It is an old type of chimneys. I don't think anyone is building such ones nowadays.

Comment: @The Photon, it could be a lined chimney. At least, it is the closest one.

Comment: The interior in your photo made me think of the National Palace in Sintra, Portugal. The references on that chimney refer to it as a "conical chimney." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sintra_National_Palace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the shape of the chimney, taking up the whole roof of the roof, it seems like a particular architectural form of a [**stone hood**](https://books.google.fr/books?id=h1s8K0_hCfoC&lpg=PA375&ots=FM4HZFNNFj&dq=%22stone%20hood%22%20middle%20ages&pg=PA375#v=onepage&q=%22stone%20hood%22%20middle%20ages&f=false). This is “hood” in the sense of

> [hood](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hood) *n.* 3d: an enclosure or canopy provided with a draft for carrying off fumes, sprays, smokes, or dusts

If instead you mean the fireplace in the center of the house, around which the other rooms are built, then it is a **hearth**

> [hearth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearth), a brick- or stone-lined fireplace, with or without an oven, used for heating and originally also used for cooking food.... an integral part of a home, usually its central and most important feature

Note that *Mantelschornstein* can also describe a kind of chimney of a steam locomotive, like the [Baden VI](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badische_VI_(alt)), in which case it is a [*petticoat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimney_(locomotive)#Function).

Comment: Thank you, Djs! Actually, I mean both the chimney and the fireplace. It would be ideal if I could combine both terms in one :-). Previously, I chose 'a conical chimney', now I could use 'a stone hood'. Thank you once again!